De Morgan's Laws Proof for Logic
Hello I am working on the logic proof for De Morgan's Law. I can only work with a very specific set of axioms, rules, and theorems and I need to prove all four implications. I am very lost on where to even start. The axioms are

$(x \vee x) \to x$
$x\to (x \vee y)$
$(x \vee y)\to (y \vee x)$
$(x \to y) \to [(z \vee x) \to (z \vee y)]$

The rule of transitivity is applicable. Substitution and Modus ponens is also allowed.
The theorems are

$(x \to y) \to [(z\to x)\to (z\to y)]$
$(\neg x) \vee x$
$x \vee\neg x$
$x\to\neg(\neg x)$
$(\neg(\neg x))\to x$
$(x\to y)\to((\neg y)\to(\neg x))$

I am confused on how to even start and help would be much appreciated!
Edit: Also there is no uses of premises. It must be derived from one of the original axioms.

How is $\land$ defined?

It is defined as (x' or y')'.

Also there is no uses of premises. It must be derived from one of the original axioms.

@waffles Are you sure that $\wedge$ is defined as 'or'? It must be 'and'.

Your def of and gives you one of De Morgan laws using Double Negation: $x \land y \equiv \lnot (\lnot x \lor \lnot y)$

Also I can't understand your question. The theorems are things you have previously proved using the axioms?

@Navid It is the negation of the negation of both (x or y). Additionally, yes the theorems are things we previously proved.

We want to prove $\neg(x \vee y)\to (\neg x\wedge \neg y)$. With your definition of $\wedge$ this is the same as $\neg(x\vee y)\to\neg(\neg\neg x\vee \neg\neg y)$. It suffices to prove $(\neg\neg x\vee\neg\neg y) \to x\vee y$ and use theorem 6. To prove this use axiom 4 repeatedly.

@waffles  You say "I need to prove all four implications", but then you present four "axioms" and six "theorems", plus there are no implications in the theorems: could you please clarify which is which (what is given and what is to prove)?  Also, you say "transitivity": is it transitivity of implication, of disjunction, of both?

If you define:
$$(x \land y) \leftrightarrow \neg(\neg x \lor \neg y)\tag1$$
Then you can use theorem $5$ (double negation) to prove that:
$$\neg(x\lor y)\leftrightarrow(\neg x\land\neg y)\tag2$$
$$\neg(x\land y)\leftrightarrow(\neg x\lor\neg y)\tag3$$
Since, by theorems $5$ and $6$:
$$(x\leftrightarrow y) \leftrightarrow (\neg x\leftrightarrow\neg y)\tag4$$
Notice how $(2)$ is equivalent to:
$$\neg(x\lor y)\leftrightarrow(\neg(\neg x) \lor \neg(\neg y))\tag5$$
By applying definition $(1)$.

This proof does not work because it must be derived from one of the axioms or theorems already proved. I am having trouble starting the actual proof.

@waffles where did I use axioms or theorems not listed?

It must start from one of the original axioms or theorems, it cannot start from the definition.

@waffles that is the definition you provided in the comments. I could remove that from the answer and the proof would be just as good, I decided to write it explicitly for clarity. The proof is fine, it doesn't assume anything you didn't state in the answer or in the comments, although it's not complete, but I believe it is trivial now, with the information given. If it isn't, let me know.
